# How to fix 'Not found: Files /bigstore/project/testing/filename.json' error when loading into Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load multiple json (4000) files into a table in Bigquery using the following command `bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --replace=true kx-test.store_requests gs://kx-gam-test/store/requests/*`, and I am getting the following error:

```
Error encountered during job execution:
Not found: Files /bigstore/kx-gam-test/store/requests/7fb27d63-5581-43a1-821d-fcf47b3412fd.json.gz
Failure details:
 - Not found: Files /bigstore/kx-gam-test/store/requests/93b54246-2284-4b85-8620-76657f4a338b.json.gz
 - Not found: Files /bigstore/kx-gam-test/store/requests/fd24a53d-2c49-4f66-bf54-a7ccf14a1cfe.json.gz
 - Not found: Files /bigstore/kx-gam-test/store/requests/35a27032-930c-456a-846d-67481a21e52d.json.gz
```

I am not sure why it is not working, is it possibly due to the number of files I am trying to load? And what is this bigstore folder prefixed in front of my GCS bucket?

I would like to highlight that the folder structure is such that there are some folders inside of `kx-gam-test/store/requests`, and I would want to load the json gzip files inside all these folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#gcs-uri):

> BigQuery does not support source URIs that include multiple consecutive slashes after the initial double slash.

Also, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_files_from) is some additional info to consider when loading data to cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check:

1. Make sure that you have the necessary [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#required_permissions)
2. Make sure that the files do exist in GCS
3. Do you have any process which deletes the file after the loading? Check the [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs) for any traces whether the file might have been deleted while BQ is actually reading/loading it.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, thanks for the suggestions, but it was not linked to file permissions and the files did exist in GCS. In the end I narrowed it down to an issue with double slashes in the uri for some of the files inside "gs://kx-gam-test/store/requests/" folder, as deleting those files solved the issue.